# Error while inserting records with Null values into SQL Server using Pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pymssql

I have a set of records that I need to insert into a Sql Server Database using pymssql. These records have the probability scores from a predictive model along with a bunch of other columns. For testing purpose, I have created an excel file with the values I want to insert into MS Sql Server Table.

Some of the records in these columns have null values which are causing issues when I try to insert them.

Below is my code

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd

conn = pymssql.connect(server='server name', user='uid', password='pwd', 
database='dbname')
cursor=conn.cursor()

#Read Scores from Excel
df = pd.read_excel("Sample_Score_Records.xlsx")

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.ANLY_SCORE([id],[scoredatetime],[score1],[score2],[model_name],[score_id],[updated_revenue_ind]) 
values(%s,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%s)", (row['id'],row['scoredatetime'],row['score1'],row['score2'],row['model_name'],row['score_id'],row['updated_revenue_ind']))
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Code works fine when I remove the columns with null values entirely from the insert statement but return the below error when I include them.

Error:

```
ProgrammingError: (207, "Invalid column name 'nan'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Below is how my data looks

```
ID  scoredatetime   Score1  Score2  Model Name  Score_id    updated_revenue_ind
0015CF3EE2  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.2564859   0.365465    Model1  sana87y47164    y
0015CF3EE3  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.215485    0.458962    Model1  sana87y47165    n
0015CF3EE4  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.3458963   0.145893    Model1  sana87y47166    NULL
0015CF3EE5  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.265489    0.987513    Model1  sana87y47167    y
0015CF3EE6  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.324896    0.154787    Model1  sana87y47168    y
0015CF3EE7  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.386492    0.482172    Model1  sana87y47169    y
0015CF3EE8  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.2489714   0.897562    Model1  sana87y47170    y
0015CF3EE9  10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.402365    0.147851    Model1  sana87y47171    n
0015CF3EE10 10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.380236    0.278968    Model1  sana87y47172    NULL
0015CF3EE11 10/17/2018 11:22:04 AM  0.361245    0.478938    Model1  sana87y47173    NULL
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: looks as though there's a bug in `pymssql`, not sure if it shouldn't be allowing column names to be referred to like that…

Comment: maybe have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722498/how-to-write-dataframe-into-mssql-using-pymssql instead of writing your own code to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Invalid column name 'nan'

The problem is that pandas does not store null values as Python `None`, it stores them as `NaN`. pymssql appears to be confused by that.

You probably should just install SQLAlchemy and then use `df.to_sql` to insert the rows:

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
# ...

#Read Scores from Excel
df = pd.read_excel("Sample_Score_Records.xlsx")

# rename one DataFrame column to match table column name
df.rename({'Model Name': 'model_name'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)

# insert rows
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://uid:pwd@servername/dbname')
df.to_sql('ANLY_SCORE', engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try and let you know if that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace dataframe NaNs with None object:
`df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)`