# Lambda failing to import CSV to RDS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm working on importing a file into SQL Server from a s3 bucket. I have no problem picking up the file, but when I try to import it into SQL I keep getting the following error:

> errorMessage": "(207, b"Invalid column name 'nan'.DB-Lib error message

My code looks like this:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
my_bucket = 'address/staging'
filename = 'anjou_mailing_list.csv'
subscriber_csv = client.get_object(Bucket = my_bucket, Key = data_filename)
data_body = subscriber_csv["body"]
csv_string = data_body.read().decode('utf-8')
sub_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), sep = ',')
#Make db connection
conn = pymssql.connect(server = 'rds_sqlserver.com', user='username',password = 'my_password', database = 'mixology')
cursor = conn.cursor()
  for index, row in sub_df.itterrows():
     cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO dbo.anjou_class(firstname,lastname, email, street, city, state, zip, country_code)
                        VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
                        '''
                        , (row['f_name']
                        , row['lname']
                        , row['email_address']
                        , row['street_ad']
                        , row['city']
                        , row['state']
                        , row['zip']
                        , row['country'])
                        )
cursor.commit()
```

Sample csv looks like such:

```
John,Doe,fakemail@gmail.com,Greenleaf CT,APT 204,Aurora,OH,48736,,
Beatrice,Winncons,heremail@gmail.com,2018 crafters,Shelbyville,IN,60505,,
```

I'm not getting a synatx error and when I run the code locally, my data is getting entered. But when I run it as a lambda function it's falling over. I thought it needed a quotechar for the apartment address so I added made a change sub_df = `pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), sep = ',', quotechar = '"')` but that seems to fail too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have nothing named `nan` in your SQL query, so I don't understand where that error comes from. But you would get a completely different error `There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause.` Are you *sure* this is the actual query?

Comment: @Charlieface I did get that error after once I added `quotechar = '"'`. It's a very misleading error that I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: Well you only have three `?` placeholders in the query, but 8 columns so that makes sense. Just realized you are using `pymssql` instead of `pyodbc`, so instead of `?` you need `%s`. Also you have a missing `)` the end, and you are not committing (or ideally just switch on autocommit)

Comment: Sorry those are typos on my end. I can go in and fix those. But pyodbc is failing in aws.

Comment: OK I'm still not getting how you are getting the error `Invalid column name 'nan'`. This error could only happen if you actually had the word `nan` directly in the SQL query, maybe you are trying to use `format` here? I'll ask you again: are you *sure* this is your actual *unmodified* code?

Comment: yeah this is my unmodified code. I'm confused as well which is why I asked here.

Comment: Looks like a bug in pymssql, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862703/error-while-inserting-records-with-null-values-into-sql-server-using-pymssql. I strongly recommend you move to a supported library such as pyodbc, see https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668

Comment: Is this the exact code of your Lambda function? `subscribers_csv` != `subscriber_csv`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry that is a typo. I can make that correction